# How to save rtsp stream without packet loss by using FFMPEG

Tags: android, ffmpeg, rtsp, live-streaming, android-ffmpeg

I am saving stream of live camera by using FFMPEG. When i am trying to save the video some data packets are loss so the video is not  playing properly.I am using following FFMPEG [Library](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java)

The command which i am sending is-

```
 String[] cmd = {"-y", "-i", "rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov", "-c:v", "libx264", "-acodec", "aac","-t", time, file_path};
 execFFmpegBinary(cmd);
```

I am also try this command but the result is same

```
String[] cmd = { "-y", "-rtsp_transport", "tcp", "-i",  "rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov", "-c:v", "libx264", "-preset", "slow", "-b:v", "500k", "-maxrate", "500k", "-bufsize", "3000k", "-vf", "scale=-1:480", "-threads", "0", "-codec:a", "libfdk_aac", "-b:a", "128k", "-t", time, file_path};
```

Here is the log of command output-

```
07-15 15:16:55.180 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:16:55.180 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 455 packets
        07-15 15:16:55.190 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:16:55.190 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 16 packets
        07-15 15:16:55.300 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:16:55.300 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 13 packets
        07-15 15:16:55.310 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45c42680] mb_type 58 in P slice too large at 31 16
        07-15 15:16:55.320 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45c42680] error while decoding MB 31 16
        07-15 15:16:55.330 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45c42680] concealing 918 DC, 918 AC, 918 MV errors in P frame
        07-15 15:16:55.330 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:16:55.330 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 55 packets
        07-15 15:16:55.340 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:16:55.340 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 19 packets
        07-15 15:16:55.340 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:16:55.350 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 1 packets
        07-15 15:16:55.350 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x458737c0] out of range intra chroma pred mode at 7 28
        07-15 15:16:55.350 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x458737c0] error while decoding MB 7 28
        07-15 15:16:55.360 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x458737c0] concealing 402 DC, 402 AC, 402 MV errors in P frame
        07-15 15:16:55.360 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45ab8020] P sub_mb_type 8 out of range at 28 14
        07-15 15:16:55.370 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45ab8020] error while decoding MB 28 14
        07-15 15:16:55.370 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45ab8020] concealing 1011 DC, 1011 AC, 1011 MV errors in P frame
        07-15 15:16:55.380 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45afe200] cbp too large (132) at 12 20
        07-15 15:16:55.380 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45afe200] error while decoding MB 12 20
        07-15 15:16:55.390 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45afe200] concealing 757 DC, 757 AC, 757 MV errors in P frame
        07-15 15:16:55.640 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : frame=  173 fps=3.6 q=28.0 size=     657kB time=00:00:23.84 bitrate= 225.8kbits/s speed=0.502x
        07-15 15:16:55.840 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:16:55.910 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 520 packets
        07-15 15:16:55.920 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:16:55.920 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 2 packets
        07-15 15:16:55.920 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:16:55.920 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 56 packets
        07-15 15:16:55.930 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x4581bb60] concealing 800 DC, 800 AC, 800 MV errors in P frame
        07-15 15:16:56.010 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45c42680] concealing 311 DC, 311 AC, 311 MV errors in P frame
        07-15 15:16:56.720 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : frame=  174 fps=3.6 q=28.0 size=     674kB time=00:00:23.88 bitrate= 231.0kbits/s speed=0.497x
        07-15 15:16:57.050 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : frame=  175 fps=3.6 q=28.0 size=     675kB time=00:00:29.00 bitrate= 190.6kbits/s speed=0.596x
        07-15 15:16:57.350 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : frame=  177 fps=3.6 q=28.0 size=     686kB time=00:00:30.36 bitrate= 185.1kbits/s speed=0.617x
        07-15 15:16:58.610 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : frame=  182 fps=3.6 q=28.0 size=     703kB time=00:00:30.56 bitrate= 188.3kbits/s speed=0.609x
        07-15 15:16:59.120 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:16:59.120 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 23 packets
        07-15 15:16:59.190 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : frame=  184 fps=3.6 q=28.0 size=     709kB time=00:00:30.64 bitrate= 189.6kbits/s speed=0.602x
        07-15 15:16:59.200 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45c42680] concealing 69 DC, 69 AC, 69 MV errors in P frame
        07-15 15:16:59.370 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:16:59.440 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 35 packets
        07-15 15:16:59.440 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x458737c0] concealing 338 DC, 338 AC, 338 MV errors in I frame
        07-15 15:16:59.920 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : frame=  187 fps=3.6 q=28.0 size=     716kB time=00:00:30.76 bitrate= 190.7kbits/s speed=0.595x
        07-15 15:16:59.920 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:16:59.990 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 20 packets
        07-15 15:16:59.990 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45afe200] concealing 489 DC, 489 AC, 489 MV errors in P frame
        07-15 15:17:01.980 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : frame=  190 fps=3.5 q=28.0 size=     737kB time=00:00:30.88 bitrate= 195.4kbits/s speed=0.575x
        07-15 15:17:01.980 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:17:01.980 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 35 packets
        07-15 15:17:02.060 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:17:02.060 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 10 packets
        07-15 15:17:02.230 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:17:02.230 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 10 packets
        07-15 15:17:02.270 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45ab8020] dquant out of range (124) at 15 35
        07-15 15:17:02.270 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45ab8020] error while decoding MB 15 35
        07-15 15:17:02.280 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45ab8020] concealing 79 DC, 79 AC, 79 MV errors in P frame
        07-15 15:17:02.280 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:17:02.280 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 76 packets
        07-15 15:17:02.290 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45c42680] concealing 805 DC, 805 AC, 805 MV errors in P frame
        07-15 15:17:02.510 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:17:02.510 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 40 packets
        07-15 15:17:02.600 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : frame=  194 fps=3.6 q=28.0 size=     747kB time=00:00:31.04 bitrate= 197.1kbits/s speed=0.57x
        07-15 15:17:02.610 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:17:02.610 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 60 packets
        07-15 15:17:02.610 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x458737c0] concealing 526 DC, 526 AC, 526 MV errors in P frame
        07-15 15:17:02.620 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x4581bb60] concealing 197 DC, 197 AC, 197 MV errors in P frame
        07-15 15:17:03.380 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : frame=  195 fps=3.5 q=28.0 size=     751kB time=00:00:31.08 bitrate= 198.1kbits/s speed=0.562x
        07-15 15:17:03.570 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:17:03.640 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 474 packets
        07-15 15:17:03.640 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:17:03.650 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 109 packets
        07-15 15:17:03.650 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x4581bb60] negative number of zero coeffs at 28 22
        07-15 15:17:03.650 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x4581bb60] error while decoding MB 28 22
        07-15 15:17:03.660 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x4581bb60] concealing 651 DC, 651 AC, 651 MV errors in P frame
        07-15 15:17:03.660 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x458737c0] concealing 1074 DC, 1074 AC, 1074 MV errors in P frame
        07-15 15:17:03.920 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : frame=  195 fps=3.5 q=28.0 size=     751kB time=00:00:31.08 bitrate= 198.1kbits/s speed=0.557x
        07-15 15:17:05.530 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : frame=  199 fps=3.5 q=25.0 size=     766kB time=00:00:32.84 bitrate= 191.2kbits/s speed=0.573x
        07-15 15:17:06.250 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : frame=  202 fps=3.5 q=22.0 size=     784kB time=00:00:32.96 bitrate= 194.8kbits/s speed=0.568x
        07-15 15:17:07.130 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : frame=  205 fps=3.5 q=28.0 size=     800kB time=00:00:33.08 bitrate= 198.2kbits/s speed=0.562x
        07-15 15:17:08.960 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : frame=  207 fps=3.4 q=28.0 size=     811kB time=00:00:35.32 bitrate= 188.0kbits/s speed=0.581x
        07-15 15:17:09.560 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:17:09.560 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 133 packets
        07-15 15:17:09.660 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : frame=  210 fps=3.4 q=28.0 size=     817kB time=00:00:35.84 bitrate= 186.8kbits/s speed=0.584x
        07-15 15:17:09.670 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:17:09.670 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 14 packets
        07-15 15:17:09.680 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45c42680] concealing 410 DC, 410 AC, 410 MV errors in I frame
        07-15 15:17:09.770 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x4581bb60] concealing 72 DC, 72 AC, 72 MV errors in P frame
        07-15 15:17:10.730 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:17:10.730 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 24 packets
        07-15 15:17:10.740 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:17:10.740 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 56 packets
        07-15 15:17:11.410 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : frame=  212 fps=3.4 q=28.0 size=     819kB time=00:00:35.92 bitrate= 186.8kbits/s speed=0.574x
        07-15 15:17:11.510 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:17:11.510 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 14 packets
        07-15 15:17:11.510 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45ab8020] concealing 77 DC, 77 AC, 77 MV errors in P frame
        07-15 15:17:11.520 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : frame=  213 fps=3.4 q=28.0 size=     820kB time=00:00:35.96 bitrate= 186.8kbits/s speed=0.568x
        07-15 15:17:11.520 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:17:11.520 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 10 packets
        07-15 15:17:11.670 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:17:11.720 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 82 packets
        07-15 15:17:11.730 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:17:11.730 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 41 packets
        07-15 15:17:11.740 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45c42680] concealing 1343 DC, 1343 AC, 1343 MV errors in I frame
        07-15 15:17:11.740 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:17:11.750 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 240 packets
        07-15 15:17:11.890 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:17:11.900 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 7 packets
        07-15 15:17:11.900 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:17:11.900 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 63 packets
        07-15 15:17:11.940 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45ab8020] out of range intra chroma pred mode at 42 32
        07-15 15:17:11.950 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45ab8020] error while decoding MB 42 32
        07-15 15:17:11.960 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [h264 @ 0x45ab8020] concealing 187 DC, 187 AC, 187 MV errors in P frame
        07-15 15:17:12.420 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        07-15 15:17:12.420 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 9 packets
        07-15 15:17:12.830 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : frame=  217 fps=3.4 q=24.0 size=     881kB time=00:00:36.12 bitrate= 199.7kbits/s speed=0.562x
        07-15 15:17:32.710 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : frame=  217 fps=2.6 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1192kB time=00:00:59.48 bitrate= 164.2kbits/s speed=0.703x
        07-15 15:17:32.720 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : video:1190kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.207405%
        07-15 15:17:32.820 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [libx264 @ 0x420a54c0] frame I:4     Avg QP:17.76  size: 23826
        07-15 15:17:32.820 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [libx264 @ 0x420a54c0] frame P:141   Avg QP:20.25  size:  7361
        07-15 15:17:32.830 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [libx264 @ 0x420a54c0] frame B:72    Avg QP:23.59  size:  1173
        07-15 15:17:32.830 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [libx264 @ 0x420a54c0] consecutive B-frames: 54.4%  1.8%  6.9% 36.9%
        07-15 15:17:32.840 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [libx264 @ 0x420a54c0] mb I  I16..4: 23.2% 42.9% 34.0%
        07-15 15:17:32.840 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [libx264 @ 0x420a54c0] mb P  I16..4:  3.6%  3.2%  1.9%  P16..4: 27.9%  6.4%  4.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:52.3%
        07-15 15:17:32.850 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [libx264 @ 0x420a54c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 20.2%  1.0%  0.3%  direct: 1.1%  skip:77.2%  L0:42.5% L1:53.9% BI: 3.7%
        07-15 15:17:32.860 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [libx264 @ 0x420a54c0] 8x8 transform intra:38.4% inter:29.9%
        07-15 15:17:32.860 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [libx264 @ 0x420a54c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 49.0% 31.1% 15.6% inter: 12.9% 10.5% 1.3%
        07-15 15:17:32.870 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [libx264 @ 0x420a54c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 72%  6%  5% 17%
        07-15 15:17:32.870 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [libx264 @ 0x420a54c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 45% 16% 17%  2%  4%  3%  4%  5%  3%
        07-15 15:17:32.880 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [libx264 @ 0x420a54c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 26% 19% 15%  5%  6%  4% 10%  9%  6%
        07-15 15:17:32.880 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [libx264 @ 0x420a54c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 46% 12% 40%  3%
        07-15 15:17:32.880 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [libx264 @ 0x420a54c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
        07-15 15:17:32.890 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [libx264 @ 0x420a54c0] ref P L0: 78.9%  6.1%  9.5%  5.6%
        07-15 15:17:32.890 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [libx264 @ 0x420a54c0] ref B L0: 87.4%  9.5%  3.1%
        07-15 15:17:32.890 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [libx264 @ 0x420a54c0] ref B L1: 95.5%  4.5%
        07-15 15:17:32.900 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: progress : [libx264 @ 0x420a54c0] kb/s:163.45
        07-15 15:17:32.900 25713-25713/com.github.sampleffmpeg V/output: SUCCESS with output : ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
        built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
        configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/i686-linux-android- --arch=x86 --cpu=i686 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/x86 --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -march=i686' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
        libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
        libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
        libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
        libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
        libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
        libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
        libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
        libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
        [udp @ 0x4203b040] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
        [udp @ 0x4203c040] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
        Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://81.109.95.91:3000/stream':
        Metadata:
        title           : Session streamed with GStreamer
        comment         : rtsp-server
        Duration: N/A, start: 0.080000, bitrate: N/A
        Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p, 720x576, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
        [libx264 @ 0x420a54c0] using cpu capabilities: none!
        [libx264 @ 0x420a54c0] profile High, level 3.0
        [libx264 @ 0x420a54c0] 264 - core 148 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
        Output #0, matroska, to '/storage/emulated/0/recording15072016-031605.mkv':
        Metadata:
        title           : Session streamed with GStreamer
        comment         : rtsp-server
        encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
        Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 720x576, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 1k tbn, 25 tbc
        Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libx264
        Side data:
        unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
        Stream mapping:
        Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
        Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
        frame=   23 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
        [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
        [NULL @ 0x4203ba00] RTP: missed 29 packets
        [h264 @ 0x45afe200] concealing 104 DC, 104 AC, 104 MV errors in P frame
        frame=   42 fps= 41 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
        frame=   47 fps= 17 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
        frame=   52 fps= 14 q=28.0 size=      36kB time=00:00:00.24 bitrate=1231.4kbits/s speed=0.0655x
        frame=   55 fps= 12 q=28.0 size=      46kB time=00:00:00.36 bitrate=1036.1kbits/s speed=0.0783x
        [rtsp @ 0x420391c0] max delay reached. need to con
```

How to save rtsp stream without packet loss with good quality ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Before you even get on the android , is there some build of ffmpeg  that works on a test stream without the loss? IMO you have issue with lib build that is narrow subset of ffmpeg. Does any more broad imple of mpeg handle the same stream?

Comment: Try increase frame rate in ffmpeg command

Comment: @RobertRowntree I am increasing frame rate but the problem is same.Actually when i am going through the dummy url and save a video of 2 min or 5 min it save the video length of 2 min or 5min but when i am playing this video somewhere it is going freeze and again continue itself.But when i am going through my app live url and save  video, video skips (for ex 22 sec to 35 sec, 40 sec t0 55 sec) like that.

Comment: lots of "max delay" messages from rtsp module.  maybe that means you need a faster, multi-core cpu that can consume all those frames without falling behind. install your ffmpeg on a faster box and run the same expression and see whether it consumes the same input without all the packet loss/drop.. ffmpeg on android is slower because of its constraints... battery , small device.  frame rate capacity on good linux box will be 10 X what u have on android.

Comment: We set our `-reorder_queue_size` to `4000` and our `-max_delay` to `10000000`, which reduced the number of lost packets but didn't completely fix the issue. We built this for a demonstration / presentation we were doing and just had to say "Good Enough!"™.

Answer (score 34):

I had exactly the same problem but I finally found a solution:

Just add `-rtsp_transport tcp` before the `-i` option, not after!

This command works for me:

```
./ffmpeg_g -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.5.163:554/live/av0 -c copy /root/test.ts
```

Comment: Ugh, using `-rtsp_transport tcp` makes it worse. Sure, it reduces the smearing but it misses lots and lots of frames instead, skipping entire seconds of video.

Comment: If someone wants to capture only 1 frame from a live stream, this works perfectly! No packet loss: `ffmpeg -y -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://<username>:<password>@<ip_address>/live[/<path>] -frames:v 1 test.jpg`

Comment: `-rtsp_transport tcp` fixed the problem for me too. The main difference between `TCP` and `UDP` is that TCP sends a receipt for received packs so the packets won't be missed (flow control). `UDP` is better if you are just watching the stream in real time and won't bother about a few freezes. If you are downloading the stream then use `-rtsp_transport tcp`, wich will ensure no packets are lost

Answer (score 5):

> How to save rtsp stream without packet loss with good quality ?

Don't reencode it. Save it as-is.

```
ffmpeg -y -i "${source}" -c copy -t "${time}" "${filepath}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to move the transport/tcp before the input command so it looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i ${source} -acodec copy -vcodec copy ${output}
```